# Want multithreaded code to work as a single transaction

Tags: java, multithreading, transactions, synchronization

I have a for loop and inside that a method (updateBalancePnlForAllPermissions)  having multithreaded code exists. My problem is I cannot remove multithreading concepts from updateBalancePnlForAllPermissions(). But in this particular case I want updateBalancePnlForAllPermissions() to leave it's multithreaded nature.
I want that even if a single entry in for loop fails in this method whole process should be stopped and whatever entries are made in db should be reverted.
Currently, if failure happens for one entry the 2nd entry execution still continues. I can say that i wnat the forloop to work as a single transaction where as soon as a failure occurs the whole transaction gets rolled back. Can someone please help? I am a newbee to multithreading and feeling lost here.

```
for (AppDate cobDate : recordsForCob.keySet()) {
    synchronized (BalanceServiceImpl.class) {
        PnlFile cobSpecificPnlFile
            = new PnlFile(pnlFile.getHeader(), pnlFile.getFooter(), Lists.newArrayList(recordsForCob.get(cobDate)));
        List<PnlBook> pnlBooks=getPnlBooks(cobSpecificPnlFile);
        try{
            updateBalancePnlForAllPermissions
                (cobDate, pnlFile.getHeader().getPnlCentre(), JEDI, pnlBooks, false, file);
        } catch(AlreadyRunningException exc){
            logger.error(exc);
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error(e);
            updatePnlUploadStatus(e.getMessage(), dirLocation,file);
            break;
       }
```

Comment: I believe what you want is to run the insert / update in one transaction. Meaning you must start a transaction outside the loop does `updateBalancePnlForAllPermissions`  and 'updatePnlUploadStatus' run as REQUIRED / REQURES_NEW?

Comment: What technology do you use?. Spring?. Can you mark / annotate the whole method as Transactional?

Comment: Agreed with Kenneth Clark that you want a single transaction.  Can updateBalancePnlForAllPermissions be changed to take a transaction to use?